# EXC_BAD_Access(code 1) or EXC_Breakpoint error occur in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am a beginner in iOS. When I run my xcode simulator and click on text field, then i set table on Text Fields but when I click, Table can't open and an error is shows which is `EXC_BADAccess (code1) or EXC_Breakpoint(i1300..)`.

Why is this happening?

This is an image of what i am getting.

[image]

```
        UITextfield *Delivery_Staff;
        UITableView *tabel_AdviseTest;
        Delivery_Staff=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,470,140,30)];
        Delivery_Staff.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
        Delivery_Staff.placeholder = @"<Select Delivery Staff>" ;
        Delivery_Staff.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
        Delivery_Staff.delegate =self;
        Delivery_Staff.tag=5;
        [scrollview addSubview:Delivery_Staff];
        tabel_AdviseTest=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(520,700,190,300)  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tabel_AdviseTest.delegate=self;
        tabel_AdviseTest.dataSource=self;
        [scrollview addSubview:tabel_AdviseTest];
        tabel_AdviseTest.hidden=YES;



        UILabel *PatientSearch=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,10,120,40)];
        PatientSearch.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
        PatientSearch.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [PatientSearch setText:@"Search Patient:"];
        [view1 addSubview:PatientSearch];

        patientname=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130,10,170,40)];
        patientname.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
       //the horizontal alignment of the text
        patientname.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        patientname.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
        patientname.contentVerticalAlignment =    UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
        patientname.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; // has a clear 'x' button to the right
        patientname.delegate =self;
        [view1 addSubview:patientname];


         [patientname addTarget:self action:@selector(SearchPatients:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

       -(IBAction)SearchPatients:(id)sender
        {
          [Testname removeFromSuperview];
          [table_SearchPatient removeFromSuperview];
          [tabel_AdviseTest removeFromSuperview];
          PatientName=patientname.text;
          NSLog(@"patname %@",PatientName);
          Count=@"0";
        NSLog(@"patname %@",self.WebService->patientname=PatientName);
        NSLog(@"count %@",self.WebService->count=Count);

        [self.WebService CallServicePatientNames:@"http://192.168.1.202:81/PatientModule/PatientService.asmx/SearchPatientjquery" Object:NULL Handler:NULL];


       table_SearchPatient=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130,50,170,200)style:UITableViewStylePlain];
       table_SearchPatient.delegate=self;
       table_SearchPatient.dataSource=self;
       table_SearchPatient.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
       table_SearchPatient.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
       [self.view addSubview:table_SearchPatient];
       SearchPatientDetail=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       SearchPatientName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       NSLog(@"arr is %@",self.WebService->ptr1);
      SearchPatientDetail=(NSMutableArray*)self.WebService->ptr1 ;
    // NSLog(@"item is %@",   SearchPatientDetail);
      SearchPatientName  =(NSMutableArray *)[SearchPatientDetail valueForKey:@"Name"];
      NSLog(@"item is %@",SearchPatientName);


// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
```

}

I have created similar custom tables 5-6 times and also have added 7-8 text fields on the same view controller. Actually I post to webservice url and then according this take data in array and tap on text field. It then opens table and select data from this accordingly. This hit 5-6 url more and do same thing here. These fields are custom created.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question and shown piece of code are not clear.Can you please format the question in proper way, give necessary punctuations also. And try to ask like , what you have did? , what you are expecting ?, and what you getting now.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and show us the backtrace.

Comment: how you add your table view on textField Click ?? please put here code of your tableView display when you click on textField :)

Comment: I have added some code also there is textfield PatientName then click on or type then open table

Comment: A stacktrace at the time of the crash would be useful but, since you're somewhere in `objc_msgSend`, try turning on zombies in your scheme and see what message you get in the debug console.